# Get the Average on column1 based on the Range between First Value (0)and Last value (0) of Column2 in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I am very new to Qlikview.

I need to get the Average of Goodpages Column ,  between the Range of First Value as `0` (which is found in 3rd row) and Last Value as `0` (which is found in 10th row). Note: The data is not static. So the value as `0` in Column (Yellow Calculated) can come in any row. I need this requirement.

```
GoodPages   YellowCalculated
315         0.35
320         0.25
300         0      --  First Value as 0 found  in 3rd row
200         0.37
250         0.17
315         0.18
350         0
345        0.68
355        0.57
325        0  -- Last Value as 0 found in 10th row
275        0.27
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want to present the result. Here is one way.

Create a straight table with dimensions ID and GoodPages. You will get the average with this expression: `avg( {<_flag_avg = {1}>} GoodPages)`. The total average will show what you are after. You can also add another expression: `only(YellowCalculated)`

```
//Script:
Data:
Load 
    RowNo() as ID,
    *,
    if(YellowCalculated = 0,1) as _flag_zero
;

LOAD * INLINE [
GoodPages, YellowCalculated
315,0.35
320,0.25
300,0
200,0.37
250,0.17
315,0.18
350,0
345,0.68
355,0.57
325,0 
275,0.27
];

minmax:
load
    min(ID) as minRow,
    max(ID) as maxrow
Resident Data
where _flag_zero = 1;

test:
IntervalMatch(ID)
Load
    minRow,
    maxrow
Resident minmax;

LEFT JOIN(Data)
LOAD 
    ID,
    1 as _flag_avg
Resident test;

drop table test;
drop table minmax;
drop field _flag_zero;
```

Comment: Thanks mickeger . Surely it will help me . I want to show only the value . So I have created text box  and used the average flag u have given.  I got the value what exactly I am looking for.

Comment: @Harish Nice :) please mark the answer as correct if that helped you.